# SOLR 1.4 - sort by flag

Tags: java, solr, scoring

I'm using SOLR 1.4. In search index I store products and categories. Each product may have multiple categories. Category should affect document's score.

e.g.

```
Category 1 (flag 8)
Category 2 (flag 4)
Category 3 (flag 2)
Category 4 (flag 1)


Product A: Category 1 + Category 2
Product B: Category 1 + Category 3 + Category 4
```

In this case, Product A should have the higher score than product B:
8 + 4 > 8 + 2 + 1

How can I implement this in SOLR 1.4? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is more a matter of sorting than scoring or relevance. Is this your only requirement?

Comment: I agree with @javanna. This sounds like a odd way of doing it. I think it would be possible if you create a multi-value float field called "flag" which contains the "flag" value associated with each category the document is tagged with. Then you utilize fuction queries to adapt the relevance model in the way you want. (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery)

Comment: @MaxCharas `Sort By Function` is available from version 3.1 and I'm using 1.4

Comment: @javanna, yes, this is a matter of sorting. I need to sort products by categories and then by product name, and then by score.

Comment: This way you'll be looking at the solr score only for product with same category and same name. Basically you're telling Solr you don't care too much about relevance. Is this correct? I'm asking to understand the direction of the answer I could give you.

Comment: @javanna, yes, I don't care too much about relevance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care too much about relevance, like you said in your comments, I'd suggest you to use sorting and avoid trying to influence the solr score. You can add a field  containing the sum of the flags related to the categories of the document, then sort using that field.

As you have pointed out you cannot use sort by function with solr 1.4, but it's useful to mention that if you upgrade to 3.x you could have a multivalued field containing the list of flags and compute the sum through a function, using it [for sorting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function).

In both cases, for documents with same flag sum and same title you'll be looking at the solr score, which isn't that important for you.

Comment: `Sort by function` is not available in version 1.4